# How to get the top frequency elements after grouping by columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame named `df`, and I want to count the top frequency elements in column `app_0`, `app_1` and `app_2` on different `sex`.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'app_0':['a','b','c','d'],
'app_1':['b','c','d',np.nan],'app_2':['c','b','a','a'],'sex':[0,0,1,1]})
```

`Input:`

```
df
    id app_0 app_1 app_2  sex
0   1     a     b     c    0
1   2     b     c     b    0
2   3     c     d     a    1
3   4     d   NaN     a    1
```

As you see, the `sex` of both `id 1` and `id 2` is `0`. For `sex 0`, `b` appears the most in column `app_0`, `app_1` and `app_2`, `c` appears the second most. So for `id 1` and `id 2`, the most frequency element is `b`, and the second most is `c`.

`Expected:`

```
df
    id app_0 app_1 app_2  sex  top_1  top_2
0   1     a     b     c    0      b      c
1   2     b     c     b    0      b      c
2   3     c     d     a    1      a      d
3   4     d   NaN     a    1      a      d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
def f(x):
    s = x.stack().value_counts()
    return pd.Series([s.index[0], s.index[1]], index=['top_1','top_2'])
```

Or use `Counter` with flattened values with [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
from collections import Counter

def f(x):
    c = Counter([y for x in x.values.tolist() for y in x])
    a = c.most_common(2)
    return pd.Series([a[0][0], a[1][0]], index=['top_1','top_2'])

df1 = df.groupby('sex')['app_0','app_1','app_2'].apply(f)

df = df.join(df1, on='sex')
print (df)
   id app_0 app_1 app_2  sex top_1 top_2
0   1     a     b     c    0     b     c
1   2     b     c     b    0     b     c
2   3     c     d     a    1     a     d
3   4     d   NaN     a    1     a     d
```

EDIT:

More general solution working if second top values not exist with `next`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],'app_0':['a','a','a','a'],
'app_1':['a','a','a',np.nan],'app_2':['a','a','a','a'],'sex':[0,0,1,1]})
print (df)
   id app_0 app_1 app_2  sex
0   1     a     a     a    0
1   2     a     a     a    0
2   3     a     a     a    1
3   4     a   NaN     a    1

def f(x):
    c = Counter([y for x in x.values.tolist() for y in x])
    a = iter(c.most_common(2))

    return pd.Series([next(a, ['no top1'])[0],
                      next(a, ['no top2'])[0]], index=['top_1','top_2'])

df1 = df.groupby('sex')['app_0','app_1','app_2'].apply(f)

df = df.join(df1, on='sex')
print (df)
   id app_0 app_1 app_2  sex top_1    top_2
0   1     a     a     a    0     a  no top2
1   2     a     a     a    0     a  no top2
2   3     a     a     a    1     a      NaN
3   4     a   NaN     a    1     a      NaN
```